# Redis write back cache still a manual task?

Tags: redis, scalable

I am working on an assignment. The REST API (developed in Spring) has a method m() which simulates cleaning of windows by a person. Towards the end the cleaner has to write a unique phrase (a string) on the window. Phrases written by all cleaners are eventually saved in the MySQL DB. So each time m() is executed, a query is made to the DB to fetch all phrases written to the DB today so far. The cleaner method m() then generates a random string as a phrase, checks it in the queried phrases to make sure its unique and writes it to the DB. So there is one query per m() to fetch all phrases and one to write the phrase. Both happens on the same table.

This is a scenario that can take advantage of caching and I went to Redis. I also think write back cache is the best solution. So every write happens, it happens to the cache instead of the DB and every read happens from the cache as well. The cache can be copied to the DB in a new thread per hour (or something configurable). I was reading [Can Redis write out to a database like PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033031/can-redis-write-out-to-a-database-like-postgresql) and it seems some years back you had to do this manually.

My questions:

1. Is doing this manually still the way to go? If not, can someone
   point me to a Redis resource I can make use of?
2. If manual is the way to go this is how I plan to implement it. Is it ideal?

   Phrases written each hour will be appended to a list of objects (userid, phrase) in Redis, the list for midnight to 1 am will be called phrases_1, for 1 to 2 am as phrases_2 and so on. Each hour a background thread will write the entire hour's list to DB. Every time all phrases are required to be fetched for checking, I will load all lists for the day from the cache e.g. phrases_1, phrases_2 in a loop and consolidate them. (Later when number of users grow - I will have to shard but that is not my immediate concern).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check https://github.com/RedisGears/rgsync (and https://redislabs.com/solutions/use-cases/caching/) which tries to address both the cases of write-back and write-through.
I'm yet to do a functionality test.

It is also interesting to note that a 2020 CMU paper (https://www.pdl.cmu.edu/PDL-FTP/Storage/2020.apocs.writeback.pdf) claims "*writeback-aware caching is NPcomplete and Max-SNP hard*"

Answer (score -1):

Instead of going to redis for uniqueness of data,you should create a unique index on the field you want to be unique and MySQL will take care of the rest for you