# Why use redis as cache layer when simple key-value variables in backend code works the same?

Tags: c#, redis, nosql, key-value, key-value-store

I was reading an answer about postgres vs redis here:

[Can Redis write out to a database like PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033031/can-redis-write-out-to-a-database-like-postgresql#answer-17037464)

It was mentioned that redis is mostly used as a cache layer rather than a Database. I'm confused, why go all the way with redis when one can use simple data structures within ones back end. For example in C#, I can use a ConcurrentDictionary to achieve an in memory datastore

Comment: It's in memory, so your have two drawbacks. 1) It's only as persistent as the process, and 2) It's process-specific - if you have a load balanced front-end, your session/cache is purely per server

Comment: Redis is not in memory? If thats the case why not just use redis as the entire database?

Comment: Redis is not is process memory

Comment: So why use it as a caches store? If its in disk, why not use it as the entire database...

Comment: @user1034912 centralized in-memory store. What happens if you start storing millions of keys on your local machine? It might run out of memory ad you're consuming additional cpu for the same.

Comment: Thank you for the replies, please answer the question I will select as best answer. If it's not relevant, we can close this question.